# i7 4790K | Shutdown while running Prime95 and RealBench

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, shutdown

The computer experiences a hard reset instantly with Prime95 "Small FFTs" torture test (also with the "Blend" test but after 30 minutes) and after 4-5 passess of RealBench benchmark without any kind of overclocking on my part (Intel Turbo Boost enabled). The temps never went beyond 80ºC but while running Prime95 I noticed the voltage going beyond 1.3v and reaching almost 4.5GHz right after the system shutdown.

- CPU: i7 4790K
- MOBO: ASUS Maximus VII GENE (running the latest UEFI firmware)
- PSU: Corsair AX860i
- RAM: Corsair Vengeance 32GB @ 1600Mhz
- GPU: ASUS GTX980 Strix
- PCIEX4: BlackMagic Intensity Pro 4K
- SSD: Samsung 850 PRO 256GB x2
- HDD: WD Caviar Black 1TB x2
- HEATSINK: Noctua NH-U12S
- CPUFAN: Corsair SP120 Performance Ed. PWM x1
- CASEFAN1: Corsair AF140 Quiet x2
- CASEFAN2: Corsair AF140 Quiet x2
- CASEFAN3: Corsair AF120 Quiet x1
- CASE: Corsair Obsidian 350D

After that, I managed to solve the problem by disabling Turbo Boost as did this person here: [Putting i7-4790K under full load causes triggers a hard reset (computer shuts down with no error message)](https://superuser.com/questions/814171/putting-i7-4790k-under-full-load-causes-triggers-a-hard-reset-computer-shuts-do) . But I wasn't happy with that and manually adjusted the CPU to 4.4GHz @ 1.2v.

Gradually, I managed to get it down to **4.4GHz @ 1.085v** and it seems stable (I'm stresstesting as I write this). Temps are maintained below 84ºC on Prime95 (although I've not tested beyond 30 minutes with that) and below 76ºC on RealBench and Intel XTU (after hours running w/100% load).

I'm planning on leaving the voltage set to manual (in spite of people from ASUS recommending to use the "adaptive" feature of the MOBO to save power and reduce temps) as some people say it causes unnecesary voltage spikes.

I don't know if related, but could the fansplitters I used to connect four AF140 fans to two individual motherboard fan headers be causing the computer to shutdown? And beyond that, what do you people think of this solution?

Thanks.

**NOTE:** the collective power draw of all fans (according to Corsair) is of 0.66A. As far as I know, ASUS motherboards support up to 1A.

Comment: I had an identical issue, but with a Gigabyte Z97X-UD5H. I put it down to a ridiculously aggressive auto overclock. Thought it was just Gigabyte but maybe the same here. The solution is to probably set a manual overclock so it doesn't up the voltage itself, but in my case simply resetting the BIOS/CMOS and loading "optimised defaults" fixed the problem.

Comment: Yes, I've heard of people with Gigabyte motherboards having similar issues with the i7 4790K, and as you suggest, I managed to solve the problem by manually adjusting the voltage, but I believe it should've worked out of the box without any issues and maybe there's a better solution out there. As for resetting the CMOS, did you do it inside the UEFI or by removing the battery? Thanks!

Comment: Mine had a reset button on the board. Removing the battery should do the same thing. Haven't tried an in-UEFI reset sorry.